# Llenar campos segun opcion elegida

Tags: javascript, php

quiero llenar dos campos según la opción elegida por el usuario.
Mi código es este:

```
<div class="form-group">
                Cuatrimestre
                <select id="cuatrimestre" name="cuatrimestre" class="form control">
                  <?php
                    $bd = new ManejoDB();
                    $bd->conectar_base($x,$x,$x);
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM x";
                    $bd->qBD($sql);
                    while ($row = $bd->obtenerReg()){
                      //echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>'".$row['descripcion']."'</option>";
                      echo "<option>".$row['descripcion']."</option>";
                    }
                  ?>
                </select>
              </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                Desde
                    <input type="text" name="desde" id="desde">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                Hasta
                    <input type="text" name="hasta" id="hasta">
                            </div>
```

código js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#cuatrimestre').on('change',function(){
                var cuatrimestre = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "getCuatri.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async : false,
                    data : { cuatrimestre : cuatrimestre},
                    success : function(data) {
                        userData = json.parse(data);
                        $('#desde').val(userData.fecha_desde);
                        $('#hasta').val(userData.fecha_hasta);
                    }
                }); 
            });
        });
```

getCuatri.php

```
$bd = new ManejoDB();
$bd->conectar_base($x,$x,$x);
$sql = "SELECT fecha_desde, fecha_hasta from Encuesta_Compras_Cuatrimestre where descripcion= '".$descripcion."' ";
$bd->qBD($sql);
$row = $bd->obtenerReg();
json_encode($row); die;
```

Ese es mi código pero no funciona.
Hago un include y el js lo tengo separado y también lo incluyo.

Qué tengo mal?
Muchas gracias, un saludo

Comment: die; ? por que terminas el script de esa forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aun no puedo comentar :(

en tu archivo `getCuatri.php` te falta imprimir el resultado

```
$bd = new ManejoDB();
$bd->conectar_base($x,$x,$x);
$sql = "SELECT fecha_desde, fecha_hasta from Encuesta_Compras_Cuatrimestre where descripcion= '".$descripcion."' ";
$bd->qBD($sql);
$row = $bd->obtenerReg();
echo json_encode($row); die;
```

Solo te hace falta el `echo` antes del `json_encode`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar.
Será porque tengo el js separado en un archivo?

Comment: Falla en la línea
userData = json.parse(data);
Json is not defined...

Comment: puedes hacer un `console.log(data)` antes de esa línea de código y publicar el resultado?

Comment: Object {fecha_desde: "2017-02-15 00:00:00.000", fecha_hasta: "2017-02-28 00:00:00.000"}

Comment: Entonces no uses `json.parse(data)` y cuentame como te va

Comment: podrías darme un ejemplo por favor?

Comment: Reemplaza 

    `userData = json.parse(data);
    $('#desde').val(userData.fecha_desde);
    $('#hasta').val(userData.fecha_hasta);` 

Por
    
    `$('#desde').val(data.fecha_desde);
    $('#hasta').val(data.fecha_hasta);`

Comment: Funcionando! Gracias